# No JPEG 2000 in Image Magick or PHP any more?

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, jpeg2000

In other questions here, I see old lists of image file formats supported by Image Magick that include support for JPEG 2000, but when I run the 'identify -list format' command from the console of my Ubuntu 18.02 system, the JPEG 2000 formats are all missing. (see below). I'm running ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114.

Searches of the WEB bring up examples showing how to convert jp2 files into other formats. But when I try these examples, I get error messages like this:

> "convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `J2K'"

If I try to use ImageMagick to convert a PNG file to JPEG 2000, it creates a file that has .jp2 in the file name, but examining the header, it is just another PNG file.

The documentation for the Imagick class at php.net says that it can read JPEG-2000 images, but when I try to read one, I get the same error "no decode delegate for this image format 'J2K'" that the convert command line program gets.

I read the git change logs for Image Magick version 7 and 6 and there is no mention of dropping JPEG 2000. Or any mention at all that it ever existed.

The GD image API in php.net mentions JPEG 2000 in several places, but when I try to use it to read a JEG 2000 image, it gives me the following error message:

> "PHP Warning:  Data is not in a recognized format"

The jp2 files that I have can be read correctly by GIMP but GIMP 2.10.28 does not have the ability to write JPEG 2000 image files. The JPEG 2000 official WEB site lists GIMP as an application that can write them, but not the version I have.

I feel like someone is trying to edit JPEG 2000 out of the timeline. I remember JPEG 2000 but nobody else does. Am I going crazy or have I jumped into a timeline where nobody else remembers it? Is there any remaining way to read a JPEG 2000 image in a PHP program or on a Linux command line?

Output from the "J" section of: identify -list format

```
Format  Module    Mode  Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ISOBRL6* BRAILLE   -w-   ISO/TR 11548-1 format 6dot
      JBG* JBIG      rw+   Joint Bi-level Image experts Group interchange format (2.1)
     JBIG* JBIG      rw+   Joint Bi-level Image experts Group interchange format (2.1)
      JNG* PNG       rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
           See http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/ for details about the JNG
           format.
      JNX* JNX       r--   Garmin tile format
      JPE* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
     JPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
      JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
      JPS* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
     JSON  JSON      -w+   The image format and characteristics
      K25  DNG       r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image Format
```

Where did the JPEG 2000 formats go?

Comment: Have you seen/tried this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/899541/how-to-enable-jpeg2000-jp2-in-imagemagick?

Comment: The amount of file formats supported by Imagick depends entirely upon the amount of formats supported by your ImageMagick installation.

Comment: In Imagemagick it comes from OpenJpeg. Do you have that delegate installed?

Comment: So I get the impression that to read JPEG2000 files in ImageMagic I have to have an additional library, called a delegate for some reason, installed on my system.

Comment: Instead of downloading the tarball, I discovered Ubuntu can install it with apt-get libopenjp2-7-dev  But ImageMagick still cannot read JP2 files. Many WEB pages say "re-build it after installing the library" but I never built it, I apt-got it. I tried un-intstalling ImageMagic and re-installing it. Still does not work. Next I want PHP to be able to read it, preferably with the GD functions, and that is not working yet either.

Comment: OK, I downloade the tarball for openjpeg, built it and installed it. This made no difference. I discovered that uninstalling ImageMagick has no effect because it is a critical system tool that many other programs depend on. How do I get it to find new delegates?

Comment: I got as far as this page before I gave up and decided to use a different file format.  https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/jasper.html